# Issue with update data by postgres pg package

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, pg

I have an app built with angular and node.js (with pg npm package, version = 8.7.1)
The app divided to microservice . Each server-app have "pg" package installed and have a connection to postgres db.
The problem is that if I run some "update" query  and after this I running getList query, then I Got the old value instead the updated object. If I add setTimeout for 5 sec then it works fine

**On my localhost all works fine. The issue occur only on heroku (with postgres on cloud) on the srever. sometimes I got the updated data and sometimes not**

Here is my code:

Client code (angular) - calling to update func and then getList func with async & await

```
  async filter({ value }) {
    const list: any = await this.getList() 
    const [myData]: any = await this.updateData(this.value) 
    const list: any = await this.getList()  // Here is the issue !!
  }
```

The function calls to API to the server like this:

```
  getList(): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(`${ENV.BASE_API}/doGetApiCalls`).toPromise();
  }
  updateData(value: any): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.put<any>(`${ENV.BASE_API}/doUpdateApiCalls`, value).toPromise();
  }
```

The server code is:
Bl code

```
async function updateData(description, id) {

    let query = updateDataQuery(description, id);
    let results = await postgressQuery(query);
    return getDataResults;
}
```

DEL code

```
function updateDataQuery(description: string, id:number) {
  const query = `UPDATE public.books
                SET description='${description}', 
                WHERE book =${id}
                RETURNING *`
  return query;

}
```

And here is the connection to postgres db (BL calling to lib by import this)

```
const DATABASE_URL = process.env.DATABASE_URL;

const pool = new Pool({
    connectionString:DATABASE_URL,
    ssl:{rejectUnauthorized: false}
  })


let openConnect = async () => {
  await pool.connect();
}

let postgressQuery = async (q) => {
  try {
    const result = await pool.query(q);
    return await result.rows;
  }
  catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

========================================================

**If I added await to client then it works fine. It takes a while for update?**

```
  async filter({ value }) {
    const list: any = await this.getList()  //
    const [myData]: any = await this.updateData(this.value) //get the RETURN from server with correct data
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000)) //added for wait for 5 sec
    const list: any = await this.getList() // then data is correct (aafer 5 sec)
  }
```

What wrong in this code above  ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `openConnect` makes no sense. You connect a client, then throw it away and never release it.

Comment: `updateDataQuery` has a sql injection security issue. Always [use parameterised queries](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries#parameterized-query)!

Comment: This is unusual (since you're making the http requests, and the db queries within them) strictly sequential. Still, in a distributed system with microservices you will have to deal with such problems, a db connection opened from a one api server might not get data that has just been committed on a different connection.

Comment: @Bergi - about openConnect, you are right.
What else it could be ? maybe I should use Client instead Pool ? It happened elso on one ms.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

It was cache issue. Just need to install this package and all fine !
https://www.npmjs.com/package/nocache

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.